# How do I declare an object as public?

Tags: vb.net

VB.net gets mad when I say:

```
Public thisTicket as new ticket
```

and insists I need to use `Dim` instead of `Public`, but this prevents me from accessing the object outside of the sub I declared it in.

Basically I am trying to do the following in one sub:

```
Public thisTicket as new ticket

thisTicket.completed = true
```

and then this in another sub:

```
if thisTicket.completed = true then

'do this

else

'do this instead

end if
```

Class:

```
Public Class ticket

    Property hasStatusChange As Boolean

    Property initialAssignmentStatus As String
    Property initialApprovalStatus As String
    Property initialCompletionStatus As String

    Property newApprovalStatus As String
    Property newCompletionStatus As String
    Property newAssignmentStatus As String

    Property wasUpdated As Boolean

End Class
```

Another question,

If I made a new property under ticket called "completionChanged as boolean"

and the criteria for that being true or false would be if the initialCompletionStatus was not equal to the newCompletion status (then it would be true),

how would I get it so that I could say:

```
if thisTicket.completionchanged = true then
```

and have it know on it's own whether it's true or not, without me having to spell out the if/then each time?

Comment: You can't declare it `Public` inside of the sub, only outside at class level.

Comment: Show the relevant code of the class. **Edit** Yes of course, `Public` can be used only on class level not in a method or property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx

Comment: I updated my OP with the class. Another question, how can I set it up to where I do a property like "completionchanged" and that property would basically compare the initial and new completion status behind the scene to see if they're different, and then if they are return a "true" value, so that within my private sub I could just go "if thisTicket.completionchanged = true then" and have it automatically know what criteria would make it true?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A Local variable in a Sub or Function or property getter or setter (i.e. in a method) lives only while the method is being executed. Before or after the call of this method, the local variable does not exist. Therefore modifiers like `Public` make no sense there.

If you need to access a variable from outside a method, make it a class member (either a field or a property).

---

Answer to second question. This is why properties exist. You can add logic to them that is executed when they are accessed.

```
Private m_completionStatus As String
Property CompletionStatus() As String
    Get
        Return m_completionStatus
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        If Value <> m_completionStatus Then
            m_completionStatus = Value
            completionChanged = True
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

And then please write

```
If thisTicket.completionchanged Then
```

and drop the " = true ". What the If-statement wants is an expression yielding a Boolean result, and a Boolean variable is such an expression in itself. There is not need to have any comparison in an If-statement.

If `completionchanged` is `True` then `completionchanged = True` is `True` also. If `completionchanged` is `False` then `completionchanged = True` is `False` also. Comparing with "= True" is a bit like multiplying a number with 1. It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like it to be a member of the class, such as a property.

```
Public Property ThisTicket As Ticket
```

And in your class' constructor initialize it.

```
Public Sub New()
    ThisTicket = new Ticket
End Sub
```

Now you will be able to access this ticket from inside of your class. However, consider whether other places in your code really need to know about this member. If they do not, make it private. If you may extend this class in the future where the subtypes would need access, make it protected.

If you decide to make it private, you can bypass making it a property and just create it as a field.

```
Private _thisTicket As Ticket
```

You should also ask yourself if thisTicket really belongs to the state of the containing object. Does the containing object process a lot of tickets? Maybe the ticket should be passed into the processing function instead of being contained. If the containing object's state does concern itself with only that one ticket throughout its life, then making it a property is valid.

As for your second question..

Create a function in Ticket to evaluate the business logic you mentioned and return the boolean value for if it has changed or not.

```
Public Function HasStatusChanged As Boolean
   logic...
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a second part of the question if you are able to answer that. If I need to submit that as a separate question instead please let me know.

Comment: You could create a function in your ticket class to compare the initial ticket status to the current ticket status and return the boolean value of it has changed or not. I would refrain from putting that sort of business logic into a property, but that's my preference.